# how to write unit test case for both normal callback and q and promise callback?

Tags: unit-testing, callback, promise, mocha.js, q

I have one function in which i have written code to handle callback like this

```
exports.CallbackExample=function(req,res)
{
   return callfunction().then(function(data)
  {
      saveData(data).save(function(err,responseData)
     {
          res.send(responseData);

     })

  });

}
```

I want to write unit test case for the above code . so i have written like this

```
var res={};
var spy=res.send=sinon.spy();
CallbackExample(req,res).then(function()
{

   expect(spy.calledOnce).to.equal('true');

});
```

but this is not working. I think the reason is that function has two different callback like first one callback (Q and promises ) and second one is normal callback ....I think may be because of that reason this is not working. I am not able to move forward because of this obstacle . so how to write unit test case for that function with out making any changes in that function ?....is that possible ? ..I hope any one of you will help me. Thanks in advance I am waiting for yours solution ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, the promises have not chained properly. Resolve it by using [Deferred](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#using-deferreds),

```
exports.CallbackExample=function(req,res) {

   return callfunction().then(function(data){
     var deferred = Q.defer();
     saveData(data).save(function(err,responseData){
          if (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
          } else {
            res.send(responseData);
            deferred.resolve(true);
          }
     });
     return deferred.promise;
   });
}
```